# How Do I pass a value of a string variable inside a list directive in freemarker

Tags: parameter-passing, freemarker

```
<#assign currentTaskDefinitionId=" ">
<#if taskHistory??>
    <#assign currentTaskActivitiId= taskHistory.taskActivitiId?number>
    <#list taskHistory.getAllTaskHistories() as item>
        <#assign taskActivitiIdForApproved = taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(item).taskActivitiId?number>
        <#if  (taskActivitiIdForApproved <  currentTaskActivitiId)>
            <p> list of all previous taskDefinitionId : ${taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(item).taskDefinitionId} </p> 

            <#elseif (taskActivitiIdForApproved = currentTaskActivitiId) && taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(item).decisionType==1>
                <#assign currentTaskDefinitionId += taskHistory.taskDefinitionId>
        </#if> 
    </#list>
</#if> 
<p> Yes I am getting the value for this:  ${currentTaskDefinitionId} </p>
```

```
#if taskHistory??>
    <#list taskHistory.getTaskHistoriesByDefinition("${currentTaskDefinitionId}")! as newItem>
        <p> User Simple ID: ${taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(newItem).userSimpleId} </p>
    </#list>
</#if>
```

As mentioned in above image, I created an empty variable "currentTaskDefinitionId" and then passed some string value to it.

Now, I want to pass the final value of this string variable inside a list.

*Note:If I hard code the value and pass it to the list I am getting my result..please see below code for your reference*

```
<#if taskHistory??>
    <#list taskHistory.getTaskHistoriesByDefinition("Activity_0wk0fiu")! as newItem>
        <p> User Simple ID: ${taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(newItem).userSimpleId} </p>
    </#list>
</#if>
```

So If I hard code it and pass the value then it is giving me the value but i am not going to hardcode it because the value of string variable "currentTaskDefinitionId" keeps on changing in different scenarios.

If anyone has any insights on this one, i would be grateful.

Comment: Try `taskHistory.getTaskHistoriesByDefinition(currentTaskDefinitionId)`

Comment: @JasperdeVries Hey thanks for your reply..yes i have tried that but still It is giving an empty report.

Comment: What's the Java declaration of `getTestHistoriesByDefintion`? I hope it has argument type like `Long`, not something generic like `Object`. I ask because I see a confusion around  its type in the template code, like, why do we need `?number` here: `taskHistory.taskActivitiId?number`, that is, why `taskHistory.taskActivitiId` doesn't already have the proper type? Also you have `<#assign currentTaskDefinitionId=" ">` but that assumes a that a `taskDefinitionId` is a string.

Comment: Just as side note, note that `taskHistory.getAllTaskHistories()` can be written as `taskHistory.allTaskHistories`. In general, `obj.getSomeProp()` can be written as `obj.someProp`. It's just nicer. Also, Jasper already pointed out, kind of, but let me emphasize that `obj.someMethod("${x}")` is not the same as `obj.someMethod(x)`, because in the earlier you convert `x` to a string, while in the 2nd you leave `x` as is. When you do a lookup in a Java `Map`, an unintended type conversion will cause a key mismatch.

Comment: @ddekany  Thanks a lot maestro. Thats a lot of insights and i agree with you. I had tried an alternative method for this with bit for hard coding.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the alternative method i have tried to get things going smooth with bit of hard coding..

```xml
<#assign currentTaskDefinitionId=" ">
<#assign listOfAllPreviousTaskDefinitionId=" ">
<#if taskHistory??>
    <#assign currentTaskActivitiId= taskHistory.taskActivitiId?number>
    <#list taskHistory.getAllTaskHistories() as item>
        <#assign taskActivitiIdForApproved = taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(item).taskActivitiId?number>
        <#if  (taskActivitiIdForApproved <  currentTaskActivitiId)>
            <#assign listOfAllPreviousTaskDefinitionId += taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(item).taskDefinitionId>
            <#--  <p> list of all previous taskDefinitionId : ${taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(item).taskDefinitionId} </p>   -->

            <#elseif (taskActivitiIdForApproved = currentTaskActivitiId) || taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(item).decisionType==1 || taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(item).decisionType==0 || taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(item).decisionType==21>
                <#assign currentTaskDefinitionId += taskHistory.taskDefinitionId>
        </#if> 
    </#list>
</#if> 
 <p>  Activity_1lwd8tu </p>
<p>  FIRST USE CASE  </p>
<#if currentTaskDefinitionId?contains("Activity_1lwd8tu")>
    <#if taskHistory??>
        <#list taskHistory.getTaskHistoriesByDefinition("Activity_1lwd8tu") as currentItem>
            <#if taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).decisionType==1>
                <p style="color:green;"> Approved By: ${taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).userSimpleId} </p>
                <p style="color:green;"> Approved By: ${taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).name} </p>
                <#elseif taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).decisionType==0>
                 <p style="color:red;"> Rejected By: ${taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).userSimpleId} </p>
                 <p style="color:red;"> Rejected By: ${taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).name} </p>
                <#elseif taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).decisionType==21>
                 <p style="color:purple;"> Picked By: ${taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).userSimpleId} </p>
                 <p style="color:purple;"> Picked By: ${taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).name} </p>
            </#if> 
        </#list>
    </#if> 
</#if> 
<p> SECOND USE CASE  </p>
 <#if listOfAllPreviousTaskDefinitionId?contains("Activity_1lwd8tu")>
    <#if taskHistory??>
        <#list taskHistory.getTaskHistoriesByDefinition("Activity_1lwd8tu") as currentItem>
            <#if taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).decisionType==1>
                    <p style="color:green;"> Approved By: ${taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).userSimpleId} </p>
                    <p style="color:green;"> Name of the task: ${taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).name} </p>
                    <#elseif taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).decisionType==0>
                    <p style="color:red;"> Rejected By: ${taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).userSimpleId} </p>
                    <p style="color:red;"> Name of the task: ${taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).name} </p>
                    <#elseif taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).decisionType==21>
                    <p style="color:purple;"> Picked By: ${taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).userSimpleId} </p>
                    <p style="color:purple;"> Name of the task: ${taskHistory.toFMTaskHistory(currentItem).name} </p>
            </#if>
        </#list>
    </#if> 
</#if>
```

Here, I will be getting many values for `listOfAllPreviousTaskDefinitionId` and `currentTaskDefinitionId`. This `currentTaskDefinitionId` is also a variable that contains a single string value but this value is not fixed or pre-decided as it completely depends on which step of taskHistory I am generating the report.